# Request tooltip rewording (or removal of edit button) when edit is not allowed

Tags: feature-request, edits, tooltips, wording

> [image]

It currently reads:

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

Which was, at least to me, a head scratcher for a moment. Note: the meta sites I frequent, I can suggest or edit all posts.

@animuson ♦ suggested:

> Suggested edits are only allowed on tag wikis on meta sites.

Which fixes the double-negative, but still remains confusing. Editing tag wikis would not cross my mind when trying to edit a post.

Is there a better suggestion?

Better yet *if* possible: **remove the edit** button when that condition applies.

Comment: The suggeated edits queue on per-site metas only accepts edit suggestions for tag wikis and excerpts - no posts. Your wording change would be inaccurate. A better wording would be removing the double negative... "Suggested edits are only allowed on tag wikis on meta sites."

Comment: @animuson: see update, as your suggestion was also a bit confusing to me, thanks!

Comment: Your suggestion is still inaccurate. Community wiki posts are different than tag wikis. Tag wikis are the info page for a tag. You cannot suggest edits for community wiki posts either.

Comment: @animuson: hopefully I got it right now, see update, thanks again

Comment: If it's confusing, perhaps it makes more sense to not even mention it there. I doubt many people are suggesting tag wiki edits on meta sites that it really matters to include that terminology in the message versus just... "Suggested edits on posts are not allowed on meta sites." It's diving into explicit details nobody asked for.